# writing codes for Sharepoint to get the URLs

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

I am new to Sharepoint.. I wanted to know if it is possible to write code to get the URLs(specifically) of documents uploaded in a sharepoint site ?

Answer (score 0):

You can Use SPFolder Class and SPFile Class. get a File URL Path

Write a sample code on Sharepoint Webpart Project.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spfolder.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spfile.aspx